# Copy an existing file at runtime using a relative path

Tags: c++, qt, copy, relative-path, qfile

I have a method which saves data into a binary file. I'm trying to unit test this method. That's why I made myself a controller binary file with the data I'm supposed to save using my method.

My folder tree looks like this :

```
C:.
├───include
    └─── header.h
├───source
│   └─── source.cpp
└───tests
    └───Test
        ├───data
        │   └── controller.bin
        └─── unitary_test.cpp
```

When running my test in unitary_test.cpp, I want to copy controller.bin to the temporary folder I create, the folder where I'm creating the file using my method under test.

The thing is that I can't manage to copy this file using relative path as my file is not found.

```cpp
QTemporaryDir dir;
std::string controllerPath = "controller.bin";
QFile::copy(QString::fromStdString("./data/" + controllerPath), QDir(dir.path()).filePath(QString::fromStdString(controllerPath)));
```

Is there a way I can do this at runtime using a relative path?

Comment: " i can't manage to copy this file using relative path" what does that mean exactly? What happens?

Comment: file is not found, hence not copied

Comment: Put that control file into a qt resource, then copy from there into a temp dir.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#explicit-loading-and-unloading-of-embedded-resources

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current working directory of the process. If you want it to be relative to the executable, you first need to figure out where the executable is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative path must be relative to runtime current directory. Probable you execute you unitary_test from another current directory where the relative path data/controller.bin doesn't exist.

Where is "unitary_test.exe" located? As far as I know, Qt Creator produces build results into the separate directory (not into the source directory)

Find unitary_test.exe and copy "data" dir to it's directory. Astually it should be done in your build script (e.g. CMakeLists.txt)